# SwiftUI: Automatic Preview Updating Error "Failed to build ContentView.swift"

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

I'm trying to run the Automatic Preview in Xcode 11, however even though the project builds successfully, the automatic preview fails giving me the error **Failed to build ContentView.swift. Failed to code sign ContentView.swift**.

I have just created the project without any modifications to the auto generated code. Even the code signing has also been set properly. Note I'm using the **Free Apple Developer Account**. Could this cause any problem?

Following is the code from ContentView.swift file:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: While I'm not sure what exactly is going on, please note Xcode 11 is a beta and there are likely weird bugs that aren't yet fixed.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First select the **Xcode** using following command

> sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Then  run

> sudo xcodebuild -license

Hope it is helpful

Comment: I tried the same on the mac terminal. On terminal first run **sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer** and then run **sudo xcodebuild -license**. Next you'll be prompted with license agreement, keep pressing '*space bar*' until reaching the end of the agreement and then type '*agree*'. Preview is working properly now. Thanks!!

Comment: Where did you find that ? I mean any doc or any link

Comment: I followed the method suggested by @tsp, but got error which was solved using ‘sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer’

Comment: For xcode beta, use sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: If you are using the preview release of Xcode 11 be sure to change the target of `xcode-select` to wherever `Xcode-beta.app` is located on your machine.

Comment: For some unknown reason, this fix doesn't work when the project name is swiftui. After I renamed the project, it started working

Comment: Not working here. Xcode 13.2.1, new project, getting 'Failed to build'. Nothing is working.

Comment: Xcode 13.3, not working.

Answer (score 24):

I solved that problem by going to the Xcode - Preferences -> Locations and assigning the Command Line Tools to Xcode 11. Also keep in mind that it is a beta, so it is unstable.

Comment: Thanks - how did you know to do this?

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm glad I helped you. I was trying for a while, it was trial and error.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as I was using // to comment beside my curly brackets to check I had them all in the right spot in my screen code. Xcode seems to cope with a few but once the screen gets too large and too many comments......
Now I comment on the line below and no problems!

Answer (score 3):

Xcode SwiftUI Previews may occasionally fail with an error message about a modified .h file, such as “file Header.h has been modified since the module file Module.pcm was built: mtime changed.” (85938686)

Workaround: Delete the Clang module cache by running the following command in Terminal:

> rm -rf "$TMPDIR/../C/clang/ModuleCache"

Then try to preview the file again.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode-Release-Notes/xcode-13_3-release-notes

Comment: This one did it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.  I solved it by moving the file location of the file I was trying to preview.  When the file was created it was down below the resources folder, so I moved it up and then preview worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently having this problem with XCode 12.2, it says "Failed to build ContentView.swift." and when you click on the information's button it says "Extra tokens at end of #SourceLocation".
Apparetly that was because i wrote a "// Comment" in the same line, next to a variable definition, so i solved this only moving the comment to the next line.
I don't know who i can help this, but just wanted to share it.
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Change your iOS version to the latest one. It will solve your issue.
[image]

Comment: But SwiftUI supports minimum iOS version 13 so why it's compulsory to update deployment info to latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Renaming main project solved same issue on my Mac.

- Rename the blue file in your project navigation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just use Latin English Characters for your project. I tried everything above. Then, I deleted the project and recreate using just English characters.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered this problem too. I download Xcode beta-1 before I download macOS 10.15. Then after my system upgrade to 10.15, the preview function didn't work. It turns out that Apple has released Xcode beta-2 version recently, so I downloaded and it worked. So, KEEP THE NEWEST VERSION OF XCODE!!!!