# Xcode preview show loading page then white screen only

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode11.3

Over the holidays I took a break from a project. Also in that time, I updated my mac to Catalina and Xcode to the newest version. Now when I run the project that worked well before it loads the loading page but then turns white.

There is no error in the Xcode, but this is what my system.log looks like:

```
n  8 17:19:25 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (UIKitApplication:com.kianco.socialapp[7251][rb-legacy][2693]): Service exited due to SIGKILL
Jan  8 17:19:25 Kians-MBP syslogd[1215]: ASL Sender Statistics
Jan  8 17:19:26 Kians-MBP diagnosticd[1246]: System mode client stopped - DTServiceHub (1311) - clearing mode: 0x0, still active: 0x9
Jan  8 17:19:26 Kians-MBP diagnosticd[1246]: Posting stream filter: "{
        global = 38655164416;
    }"
Jan  8 17:19:27 Kians-MBP logd[1226]: assertion failed: 19C57 17A844: logd + 57925 [7745E081-E54A-3EBA-B513-57B72326CC0A]: 0x2
Jan  8 17:19:33 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Jan  8 17:19:33 Kians-MBP diagnosticd[1246]: Posting stream filter: "{
        category =     {
            heartbeat = 34360131584;
        };
        global = 38655164416;
        pid =     {
            1311 = 34360131584;
            2773 = 34360131584;
        };
        subsystem =     {
            "com.apple.dt.instruments" = 34360131584;
            "com.apple.runtime-issues" = 34360131584;
        };
    }"
Jan  8 17:19:33 Kians-MBP diagnosticd[1246]: System mode client started - DTServiceHub (1311) - mode: 0x8, filter: "{
        category =     {
            heartbeat = 0;
        };
        pid =     {
            1311 = 0;
            2773 = 0;
        };
        subsystem =     {
            "com.apple.dt.instruments" = 0;
            "com.apple.runtime-issues" = 0;
        };
    }"
Jan  8 17:19:35 Kians-MBP socialapp[2773]: assertion failed: 19C57 17A844: libxpc.dylib + 83383 [F391B106-5033-3156-98D9-705C5A7FDECD]: 0x7d
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.DocumentManagerCore.Downloads): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.DocumentManagerCore.Downloads): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.FileProvider.ArchiveService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.FileProvider.ArchiveService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.FontServices.FontProviderLoader): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.FontServices.FontProviderLoader): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.FontServices.GSFontServices): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.FontServices.GSFontServices): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.FontServices.UserFontManager): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.FontServices.UserFontManager): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.MTLCompilerService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.MTLCompilerService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.MediaPlayer.RemotePlayerService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.MediaPlayer.RemotePlayerService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.Photos.CPLDiagnose): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.Photos.CPLDiagnose): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.Safari.History): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.Safari.History): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.SafariFoundation.AutoFillHelper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.SafariFoundation.AutoFillHelper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.SafariFoundation.CredentialProviderExtensionHelper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.SafariFoundation.CredentialProviderExtensionHelper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.SafariServices.ContentBlockerLoader): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.SafariServices.ContentBlockerLoader): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.StreamingUnzipService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.StreamingUnzipService): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.WebKit.Networking): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.WebKit.Networking): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.WebKit.WebContent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.WebKit.WebContent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.avkit.SharedPreferences): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.avkit.SharedPreferences): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.backboard.display.archive): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.backboard.display.archive): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.ctcategories.service): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.ctcategories.service): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.intents.intents-helper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.intents.intents-helper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.socialapp.2773): com.apple.photos.ImageConversionService (lint): XPC Service Info.plist is missing XPCService dictionary
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.socialapp.2773): com.apple.photos.VideoConversionService (lint): XPC Service Info.plist is missing XPCService dictionary
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.textkit.nsattributedstringagent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.textkit.nsattributedstringagent): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.uifoundation-bundle-helper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnableTransactions
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.uifoundation-bundle-helper): Unknown key for Boolean: EnablePressuredExit
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.socialapp.2773): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Applications/Computer Science/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaConversionService.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.photos.VideoConversionService.xpc, error = 107: Malformed bundle
Jan  8 17:19:36 Kians-MBP com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4C640D94-3164-43DC-8340-0A015C8E3785[1213] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.socialapp.2773): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Applications/Computer Science/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaConversionService.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.photos.ImageConversionService.xpc, error = 107: Malformed bundle
```

I have tried all the tips on other posts similar to this but nothing has been effective. Through print statement testing I found that my View Did Load and View Did Appear are both running on my initial view controller. If it is any information I am using Google Firebase, Keychain Wrapper and IQKeyboard.

Everything is appreciated and please ask for any other information.

Comment: Once try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56448959/10584330
And also check Xcode - Preferences -> Locations and assigning the Command Line Tools to Your Xcode Version.

Comment: Welcome @XXXOMEGALORDXXX