# "project.app" needs -Onone Swift optimization level to use previews

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Trying to integrate SwiftUI into an large existing project. I have followed steps to integrate this into my project, but when I try to preview my new SwiftUI view file, I get the error..

```
Cannot preview in this file - current target needs adjusted build settings
```

There is a little (i) symbol at the end which states..

```
"project.app" needs -Onone Swift optimization level to use previews
```

I have added my Scene delegate though the SwiftUI file is not the root view controller so I made careful attention of leaving willConnectTo method empty.

By default under my Project < Build Settings < Swift Compiler - Code Generation < Optimization Level..  Debug is set to No Optimization[-Onone], release is Optimize for Speed[-O]... This is the same settings as my practice SwiftUI project.

I have tried a number of solutions but nothing has worked yet.

[Reviewing the license agreement in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56448959/6184696)

[Checking my Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56449249/6184696)

[Edit my Info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57361613/6184696) - Though this didn't solve it, it seems like this was something important to do.

[Ultimate Explanation For Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56515686/6184696) that I followed

Comment: Well not proud of this, but I found one spot that targeted iOS 13.0, and another ios 13.1.. please let me know if I should delete this, mind you these links are quite helpful for converting an old project to Swift UI

Answer (score 41):

Ensuring the **Debug** config is chosen in Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Build Configuration helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: I had the same issue. It is silly that whole preview fails because of this.

Comment: The part that bothers me is I already upvoted this answer...

Comment: I set run to release and started getting this error, your suggestion fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Setting both **Optimization level**  to : **✓ No optimization (-Onone)** worked for me.

See resolution ▶︎: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li6vp.png